# Unable to get and update CSS style in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I am trying to get a CSS original style of a table element, and apply new style on click, if I click another cell the same would repeat and also I will retain the original style of the first element. I tried following code and it works perfectly in chrome but not in safari on a Mac.

```
    var a="";
    var style="";
    $(".fc-future").click(function(){
    $(".fc-today").removeClass('fc-today');
    clear(a, style);
     $(this).css('background-color', '#f4ccbc');
       style = css($(this));
        a=this;
    });
    var divItems = document.getElementsByClassName("fc-future");
    function clear(id, style){
            if(id){
                id.style = style;               
            }
    }


    function css(a) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {      
            if (a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
    }

    function css2json(css) {
    var s = {};
    if (!css) return s;
    if (css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
        for (var i in css) {
            if ((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
            }
        }
    } else if (typeof css == "string") {
        css = css.split("; ");
        for (var i in css) {
            var l = css[i].split(": ");
            s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the problem is the cache from your browser.

Have you clean your cache browser?

**Try this**:

For version 4 and newer:

Hold down the `⇧` Shift key and click the Reload toolbar button.
For version 3 and older:

Hold down the `⌘` Cmd key and press R. This kind of "regular" reload will usually bypass the cache.

Extracts from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Comment: nope not working, i am getting error in console, syntax error unrecognized expression:input[type=number]::webkit-outer-spin button

Comment: @PattatharasuNataraj, could you please put your html code?

Comment: it was dynamic ruby code ya, really big thats why i didn posted